# Libgdx getAzimuth() doesn't working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, accelerometer, azimuth

I want to control something in my game with the Accelerometers sensor.

I don't know why but the **getAzimuth doesnt works** it always got the **value 0**, I made this test by showing the result of some methods and this is the output

**Sample of Code** :

```
font.draw(batch, "Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() : " + String.valueOf(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()), 10, 200);
```

**The output** :

```
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() : -8.245
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() : 0.457
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ() : 1.245

Gdx.input.getAzimuth() : 0
Gdx.input.getPitch() : 0
Gdx.input.getRoll() : 0
```

**Other problem** :

getAccelerometerX(), etc, works but **even when the phone is lay on a table** those **numbers always changes**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your device either doesn't have a compass, or you have disabled the compass in your AndroidApplicationConfiguration. In either of those cases `getAzimuth()`, `getPitch()`, and `getRoll()` will return 0.

Comment: Ok, but I didn't really get what is difference between getAccelerometerX() and getAzimuth(), What is difference between the compass and the accelerometer, I don't get it.

Comment: Accelerometer measures gravity acceleration, while the azimuth is the angle between the magnetic north and another arbitrary point.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer values show the device orientation to the ground. The azimuth according to geographical orientation (meaning magnetic north etc).